# Tricky Integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left[\frac{\sec^2 \theta}{2}\cdot \exp(\frac{\sec^2 \theta}{2})\right]^{-1} d\theta$ - Brain Slayer

Tags: integration, closed-form

Given the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\left[\frac{\sec^{2}\left(\theta\right)}{2}
\exp\left(\frac{\sec^{2}\left(\theta\right)}{2}\right)\right]^{\,-1} \mathrm{d}\theta
$$
How am supposed to evaluate it within few minutes $?$. Is there a quick trick solve the integral $?$.

Should you wish to see my attempt at doing so, then you should know that my solution is analyzed the author's one, because I could not solve it without seeing clues. So, I would like to get some ideas from; I think that I fail to solve this guy because I could not see something...

Comment: Try $x=sec^2(\theta)$, at least part of it becomes a gaussian times a polynomial which has a well known integral.

Comment: Yes, when I tried - that was the 1s thing came to my mind, but did not work. The thing that solves this is to make identity using differentials and then based on Gauss' integral value get the answer - that worked; but how I was supposed to occur to the solution manner, which remains unclear until now.

Comment: Try $t=\tan\theta$

Comment: By $y = \sec^2 \theta$, I have come to $\int_1^\infty e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y^6}dy$ - interesting. By $y = \tan \theta$ to $\int_0^\infty \frac{2}{(1+y^2)^2}e^{-\frac{1+y^2}{2}}dy$. Trying to complete solution.

Comment: Introducing a new function $I(k) = \int_0^\infty \frac{2}{(1+y^2)^2}\cdot e^{-\frac{k(y^2+1)}{2}}dy$ and differentiating it twice, have got $d^2I/dk^2 = \sqrt{32\pi} \cdot \frac{1}{e^(\frac{k}{2}) \cdot \sqrt{k}} = \alpha \cdot \varphi(k)$.

Comment: The integrand of the function $\varphi(k)$ resembles the Gauss integral once more, so we are going to integrate it from 0 to infinity and get $dI/dk = 8\pi\sqrt{2}$, from here we may find that $I = 8\pi\sqrt{2}k+C$ and then setting $k = 0$ to get $I(0) = \pi/2$; the terminal step is to determine $C$ to be $\pi/2$ and then $I = \pi/2$. Don't remember if the answer is true. If not, gonna integrate without definite integrals.

Comment: Nope. The answer is $\sqrt{\pi/2e}$, making me think about Laplace integrals.

Comment: It might be better to put what you have in the comments into the question body (so others can see your attempts easier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be surprised if one can solve this integral within a few minutes without any prior knowledge. But there are some ideas that helps tackle this integral.

**1.** Write

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (2\cos^2\theta) e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sec^2\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta. $$

If you see an exponential function of something other than linear or quadratic polynomials inside the integral sign, then that integral is highly unlikely to be tackled directly except for some lucky cases. So, if we believe that this integral can be computed in a closed form, then we may first try to make the exponent simpler. Here, let us make the substitution $x = \tan\theta$. Then

$$ I = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+1)} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

**2.** If we write $y = x^2 + 1$ for simplicity, we now that the integrand takes the form $\frac{1}{y^2} e^{-y/2}$. Both the factor $\frac{1}{y^2}$ and the exponential $e^{-y/2}$ suggest that we might possibly use the trick:

$$ \frac{1}{y^2} = \int_{0}^{\infty} s e^{-ys} \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

Plugging this to the integral $I$ above and interchanging the order of integration, we indeed confirm that the integral now assumes a much familiar form:

$$ I
= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} s e^{-(x^2+1)(s+\frac{1}{2})} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}s
= \sqrt{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{s}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^{1/2}} e^{-(s+\frac{1}{2})} \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

Although we can push this direction further to find the value of $I$, we will stop at here as it is already covered in another answer.

This trick can be thought as a generalization of integration by parts. As such, it serves as a versatile tool for computing many other tricky integrals. Here is another example of this sort:

> **Exercise.** Using the above trick, show that
> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$
> (*Hint:* $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-sx} \sin^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{2}{s(s^2+4)}$ for $s > 0$.)

**3.** Alternatively, we may ask if we can "cancel out" $\frac{1}{y^2}$ factor, since the integral will be much easier to compute if this factor were not there. This idea can be realized by invoking the Feynman's trick: Let

$$ f(s) := 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2} e^{-s(x^2+1)} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Then $I = f(1/2)$, and using the gaussian integral we check that

$$ f(\infty) = f'(\infty) = 0, \qquad f''(\alpha) = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s(x^2+1)} \, \mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}} \, e^{-s}. $$

Then applying the "initial" condition $f'(\infty) = 0$ to $\int \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}} \, e^{-s} \, \mathrm{d}s = \pi \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) + C$ gives

$$ f'(s) = \pi (\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) - 1). $$

Similarly as before, using

\begin{align*}
\int \pi (\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) - 1) \, \mathrm{d}s
&= \pi s (\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) - 1) - \int \sqrt{\pi s} e^{-s} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \pi s (\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) - 1) + \sqrt{\pi s} e^{-s} - \int \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{s}} e^{-s} \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \pi s (\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) - 1) + \sqrt{\pi s} e^{-s} - \frac{\pi}{2} \operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) + C
\end{align*}

and applying the "initial" condition $f(\infty) = 0$,

$$ f(s) = \pi \bigl( s - \tfrac{1}{2} \bigr) (\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{s}) - 1) + \sqrt{\pi s} e^{-s}. $$

Plugging $s = \frac{1}{2}$ gives the desired answer.

This is another versatile tool for computing many tricky integral. The key idea is to perturb the integrand by introducing an auxiliary parameter, and performing some calculus to the resulting integral regarded as a function of that parameter.

In the following example, both the idea in part 2 and Feynman's trick is utilized:

> **Exercise.** For $a > 0$, consider the integral
> $$ f(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} a \cos(ax)\sin(ay)e^{-a xy} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y. $$
> Computing this in two ways to show that
> $$ f(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y \sin(ay)}{y^2 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}y. $$
> Using this, check that $f'(a) = -f(a)$ and $f(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. The unique solution of this equation for $a \geq 0$ is $f(a) = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a}$, hence it determines the value of the above integral.

Comment: That is what I felt - Laplace integrals are into action... Much obliged!

Comment: Other answers are great as well as yours; the reason that your answer has been accepted is owing to the efforts which you put into answering my question.

Comment: I solved your exercise easily - but did not get your logic and idea. That is why I am writing this. I tried to use the hint, but eventually, noticed that $\frac{1}{x}$ does not allow me to execute your algorithm. For this purpose, I found a nice expression for this term: $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-xt}dt = \frac{1}{x}$. The next step is the Fubini theorem (whose usage I must justify!!!), and I got stuck. However, I did not use Laplace transform but Feynaman trick: $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-xt} \sin^2 x}{x}dxdt$, which led me to your hint, and the answer that I got is $\pi/2$.

Comment: The second exercise is also not so difficult: Fubinit -> separation of integrand -> integration by parts or Laplace transform result -> terminal result. I got both formulae and feel happy.

Answer (score 4):

$$I=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^2 x e^{-\frac{1}{2}sec^2 x} dx$$
Let $\tan x=t$, then
$$I= 2e^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{(1+t^2)^2} dt=
=2e^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2/2} \int_{0}^{\infty} z e^{-z(1+t^2)} dz.$$
$$\implies I=2e^{-1/2} \int_{0}^{\infty} ze^{-z}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(1/2+z)t^2}dt=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{z e^{-z}}{\sqrt{1+2z}} dz$$
Let $1+2z=u^2$ then
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} e^{-1/2}\int_{1}^{\infty} (u^2-1)~ e^{-(u^2-1)/2} du=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2} \int_{1}^{\infty} (u^2-1)e^{-u^2/2}du=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2e}}.$$

Comment: Well, that is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$I= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac12{\sec^2 \theta}\>e^{\frac{\sec^2 \theta}{2}}\right)^{-1} d\theta
= J\left(\frac12\right)
$$
where

$$J(a)=2 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{e^{-a\sec^2\theta}}{\sec^2\theta}d\theta, \>\>\>\>\>\>\>J’(a)= -2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-a\sec^2\theta}d\theta, \\
J’’(a)=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-a\sec^2\theta}\sec^2\theta d\theta
= 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-a(1+\tan^2\theta)}d(\tan\theta)=\frac{\sqrt\pi e^{-a}}{\sqrt a}
$$
and $J(\infty)=J’(\infty)=0$. Then
\begin{align}
I &=J\left(\frac12\right)=-\int_{\frac12}^\infty J’(a)da\\
&=\int_{\frac12}^\infty\left( \int_a^\infty J’’(s)ds \right)\>da
=\int_{\frac12}^\infty\left(\int_{\frac12}^s J’’(s) da\right) \> ds\\
&=\int_{\frac12}^\infty (s-\frac12) J’’(s) ds
=\int_{\frac12}^\infty (s-\frac12)\frac{\sqrt\pi e^{-s}}{\sqrt s}ds\\
& =-\sqrt\pi \int_{\frac12}^\infty d(\sqrt s e^{-s} ) 
=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2e}}
\end{align}

Comment: Seeing how you solve problems both here and in Physics Stack Exchange makes me think I am either not genius or something like non-smart person :) Why did it not come into my mind. Thanks! Have a great day! Be happy and have a splendid Christmas!

Comment: @sergeiivanov - appreciate the compliments; rather flattering